# Is it worth it to create static libraries for iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, static-libraries

There is code that I want to include in most of my projects. Things like AFNetworking, categories for CoreData and unit testing, etc.

It seems logical to include all of these in a static library, and then use it in each project. I've noticed though, that many third-party libraries (like AFNetworking, and it's predecessor ASIHTTP) are included in projects by copying over all of their source files and then manually linking the necessary libraries to the project target.

This seems to me like the easiest way. It took a fair amount of time to figure out how to include an existing static library into a project. Even after I knew how, it still seems like a pain to do it for every new project. Also, the header search paths that you specify are to a local directory with the static library's files. Wouldn't it be easier, and is there a way, to copy the static library's files into the project? This is the same idea as including the class files directly like most libraries seem to do already, but it would be more organized because everything would be lumped into one library project, instead of having class files everywhere and having to include every one of them.

Static libraries feel like they should be the right way to go. Make a library that can be used with all projects that includes classes that every project will need. Makes sense. I am just conflicted because it seems like the right way to go is to leave everything out of a 'formal' library, and just copy over all of the class files instead.

I guess I am just looking for what experienced developers find to be the best option.

Comment: There is some good discussion on building your own "static framework" at (Cocoanetics)[http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/05/making-your-own-iphone-frameworks-in-xcode/].

Comment: @JodyHagins Error 404 - Not Found

Comment: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/04/universal-static-libraries/ and http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/05/making-your-own-iphone-frameworks-in-xcode/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would be among the first to admit that the process of referencing a static library in Xcode is not entirely intuitive. However, using a static library is the best option, without a doubt.

The main reason is maintainability: when you copy source code of a library to many places, you must remember to update all of them to the latest code when you upgrade to the next version of the library. This may be a rather error-prone process, especially when the underlying library source changes significantly (e.g. new files are added, old files are renamed, etc.)

Comment: Ok. So let's say I create a project and add my static library to it. I change the Headers Search path to be wherever the static library is on my machine and everything is fine. But what if there are many developers working on the project? Wouldn't this mean that when they check out my project, they will need my static library in the same relative directory as I had it?

Comment: @LoganSerman A standard solution to this is to use a repository for external binary dependencies. The simplest solution that I have seen used in multiple companies is to check in the binary artifacts of your library in a separate place in your source control - say, an `external/lib_afn/ver1.23/` folder. Now everyone checks out that folder into the same place in their file system, and the reference that you set up on your machine becomes valid for everyone.

Comment: So if the static libraries are in a separate location, what does this mean when the final app is compiled and released? It has to include the static library files, right? Even though the files are external?

Comment: @LoganSerman When you compile your app, Xcode links the static library into the finished artifact that you ship. Once the build is done, it does not matter that `AFNetworking` code came from a static library or from the source: it becomes part of your app either way.

Comment: Yeah, the big problem with static libraries is that they're so hard to configure, build, and use on Xcode.  Conceptually they're great.

Comment: It's a shame. I'm going to use them and assume that in the future, XCode will have an easier time automating a lot of these processes.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight but Git submodules solve the maintainability issue you mention in your answer.

Comment: @MattDiPasquale What in the world does source control have to do with all this???

Comment: Even better is to distribute the static libraries as frameworks. That way, the headers associated with the library, plus any other docs or resources that are associated with it, can be distributed in one bundle. This approach addresses @Logan Serman's valid concern as all header paths are now relative to the framework and imports for all projects simply look like:        `#import <MyFrameworkName/theHeaderName.h>` .

Answer (score 3):

There's a halfway solution - make an XCode project that builds your static library from source and put that into a shared repository (ie.. git submodule etc) which is included from each project's main repository.

Each of your projects would include this submodule and project. Then they get the latest source code each time they pull that submodule. If you set this up as a build dependency it will build a static library the first time you build and then XCode is smart enough just to include it each subsequent build so you get the benefit of fast build times.

You also get the advantage of having the source right there for stepping though / debugging.

If it's in a separate XCode project and a new version of a library adds or removes a source file you would only need to change that shared project - all your individual projects wouldn't change at all.

Answer (score 1):

What about using [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org/)? This tool does exactly what you want in a declarative way: you have a file (Podfile) where you declare your dependencies, and the tool downloads all the dependencies and builds a static library that gets added to your project.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree that static libraries feel like they might be the correct way to go for a number of reasons, but can also introduce some issues.

The positives would be creating an easy way to add a library to a project.  Although not completely intuitive, it is rather trivial to add a static library to a project after one does it a few times.  Add the files, add the search path, done.  This could also be useful in certain source control situations.  Also, updating a library may be easier.

I think the real problem here is for the open source community.  By including, say AFNetworking, for example, as a static library, you lose all access to the implementation files. This is a great feature of including source rather than a library.  It lets you change code to how you see fit, and hopefully give back.

Comment: No, you can add a static library and include the source files by including it as a cross project reference or as another project of a workspace. See [@deanWombourne's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12320743/242933).